# Is the term USERS the right word to describe active members on Stack Exchange Sites?

Tags: discussion, users

Firstly, let me say that I am currently indifferent on this matter. It is just something I have thought semi-deeply about recently, and I can see reasons to keep the status-quo and reasons for changing to a more appropriate/relevant term for how Stack Exchange refers to its "users". I would like to hear from some "users" here, and what their opinion on this matter is. I would also like to hear from at least one moderator and/or staff member on their opinion and/or the company's opinion on this matter.

> Some usability professionals have expressed their dislike of the term
>   "user", proposing it to be changed.
>
> Don Norman stated:
>   One of the horrible words we use is "users". I am on a crusade to get rid of the word "users". I would prefer to call them "people".
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_%28computing%29#Criticism

https://stackoverflow.com/users/
[image]

---

https://stackoverflow.com/users/3041194/lowerclassoverflowian
[image]

---

**A couple reasons to keep the term "users".**

1) User simply refers to a person that is doing stuff primarily with the help/use of a tool. In this case, the tool is the stack exchange website and all of its functions, features, etc included therein.

2) Users may not be technically correct to describe people who ask questions, answer questions, edit posts, review posts, provide content for the website. However, it is not seen as an offensive/derogatory word by most people, and everything is already set up with the term "users", like folder/website locations/pages, etc, so no point in changing everything for something that is not a big deal in the first place.

**Reasons to change the term "users" to something else.**

Users is not a correct term for people who provide content for Stack Exchange and all the people who view that content now and in the future. The term user, implies that the person is just using something without contributing to the success, quality, or effects of it's purpose.

For example, a person who uses a hammer to nail a nail in the wall to hang a picture, could be said to be a user of that hammer. In this context, the term user would be correct because the person is not developing, designing, constructing the hammer itself. They just bought it at home depot and don't do anything to improve the quality, durability, effectiveness of said hammer.

So as you can see.. Users is not an appropriate term for anyone who asks at least 1 question, or answers at least 1 question on a Stack Exchange Site.

If the term "users" was changed, what should it be changed to?
- members
- contributors
- ...

Comment: I would say member would be a more correct term

Comment: *"The term user, implies that the person is just using something without contributing to the success, quality, or effects of it's purpose."* - You better go tell the entire Internet that they used the wrong term.

Comment: "user" seems more technically correct here than "person".  Even if "person" might "sound better".  If I create two accounts I'm not two different people, but I *am* two different users.  It is technically incorrect to say that I'm two different people.

Comment: "Exchangers" (Good thing comments can't be downvoted)

Comment: On a more serious note, "Contributors" would represent exactly what we do here.

Comment: Well, these days the team is working to change "sites" to "communities" all around the place. So "member" is natural for a community in my opinion. :)

Comment: On a side note I see your point. I similarly dislike the dehumanising "Human resources"

Comment: Why not "Overflowians"? It's right there in the OP's display name.

Comment: The correct word you are looking for is "serf"

Comment: Status quo is fine honestly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't say "user" is technically incorrect but it is broad:

A user is [defined as](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_%28computing%29):

> A user is a person who uses a computer or network service. A user
> often has a user account and is identified by a username (also user
> name). Other terms for username include login name, screen name (also
> screenname), nickname (also nick), or handle, which is derived from
> the identical Citizen's Band radio term.

So user name certainly applies to Stack Exchange, **but** it could just as easily apply to a purely passive activity where you are only consuming information

A member is [defined as](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/member):

> One that belongs to a group or an organization: a club member; a bank
> that is a member of the FDIC.

Again, this seems to apply to Stack Exchange. It also implies a level of inclusiveness and mutual interation; being a member of community. User certainly doesn't preclude this, but nor does it imply it.

### Conclusion

Either "user" or "member" seems technically correct. However; "member" seems more inclusive and more suggestive of a "community".

Comment: "member" isn't more inclusive at all, it's much more restrictive. You say it yourself: *"User certainly doesn't preclude this, but nor does it imply it."* You can be a user of the site without belonging to some community. using "member" would just exclude all the other users that are not here for some kind of social networking.

Comment: @sth I think we're using narrow/broad and inclusive/non-inclusive interchangably. But I don't think community automatically equals social network

Answer (score 13):

Different people use the site in different ways. It may sound sweet to call them all "people" but the world is full of people who have nothing to do with this site. We have a word for people who not only look at the questions and answers, which is a form of using you can do without registering, but who also register, adopt an identity, and possibly (ok almost certainly) earn reputation. It is important to choose a nice short noun for this, because it will also be used as an adjective in constructs like "user name", "user profile", "user number" and so on.

Consider some candidates:

- Contributor. Not everyone contributes. Some just read. Yet they have registered and have a name and a profile and all that. Both contributing and reading count as using the sites.
- Member. Meh. I get it, community, club, belonging and all that, but no better than user really. It says nothing about what you do.
- Person. Silly. We don't confer personhood on you when you sign up. Also a great source of pluralization bugs.
- Exchanger. No. Just no.

I don't even see what's wrong with the word user. I'm a Twitter user - my usage consists almost entirely of making content. Ditto Facebook, Connect (a Microsoft site where you report bugs so they can be declined, declared no-repro, or declared a dupe of something unrelated), and pretty much every web site that I need a password to use. Bottom line, for me, this paragraph of yours:

> Users is not a correct term for people who provide content for Stack Exchange and all the people who view that content now and in the future. The term user, implies that the person is just using something without contributing to the success, quality, or effects of it's purpose.

is just plain wrong and not accurate.

Answer (score 9):

> The term user, implies that the person is just using something without contributing to the success, quality, or effects of it's purpose.

Ummm, no. That is plainly wrong. A user is someone that **uses the services provided.** Be it simply content that's displayed on a page, a way to post comments, or a way to post questions and answers, you're always *using* something.

Comment: Good use of logic.

Comment: @Lower But your reasons for the change are an incorrect definition and some random guy no one has heard of that was linked on Wikipedia saying it's bad. There's not much to go on.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian: Before you **assume** that people who have downvoted your suggestion "don't know how to read and comprehend correctly", have you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta?

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian: Your title asks a question. I think it's entirely reasonable to interpret a downvote as "No, there shouldn't be a change." Whether or not you *want* a change is irrelevant - the question is effectively *suggesting* the change. Also, regardless of the change, you make claims which can be disagreed with: "Users is not a correct term for people who provide content for Stack Exchange and all the people who view that content now and in the future." I disagree with that claim.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian: And after your question change, I still disagree with the premise of the question, so my downvote stands. Do you think that a telephone service user isn't a user because they're contributing their voice? Is someone not "using" a notebook when they write in it? I'm not a developer of the site - I contribute to it, but that in no way stops me from being a user of it. There are many words which *can* be used to describe my involvement in the site; I'm not *just* a user, but I certainly *am* a user.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian: The guy with the hammer would be both "maker" and "user" of the hammer, if he made it and uses it. I don't see why that would need to be exclusive.

Comment: Don Norman is not a random guy no one has heard of. He's a respected thinker in design and UX engineering. Anyone who makes things another person will use should read The Design of Everyday Things.

Answer (score 6):

This would be an interesting debate on English.SE, but I have to echo my peers here - "users" is *used* a lot.

People? Dear no, that would lead to all kinds of jokes.

"Contributor" ? It would be good in formulating haikus, but it's long-winded.

"Member" ? There's a double-entendre, so no.

The phrase "new user" is mainstream(about 42M hits on Goog). It is neutral and bland also.

This is a technical site, we stay neutral

Comment: I agree that "people" is madness since it isn't true. Only members of the site are listed, not all people

Comment: However I would say **everything** is a double entendre, and "member" isn't that much of a double entendre (perhaps it is more so in the US; I've only heard it in US media)